# How can i access certain columns value in for loop csv python

Tags: python, csv

this is my csv file:

```
a,b,c,d,e,
0,100,0,0,0
0,1500,0,0,0
0,2350,0,0,0
0,3700,0,0,0
0,5060,0,0,0
```

and my python code:

```
import csv, os, sys
y = int(sys.argv[1])

with open("csvinput.csv", 'rb') as input, open('temp.csv', 'wb') as output:
        reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter = ',')
        writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = ',')

        all = []
        header = next(reader)
        header.insert(0, 'ID')
        all.append(header)
        count = 0
        del header[1]
        del header[-1]
        for row in reader:
                kount = row[1]
                count += 1
                while y<kount:
                        del row[0]
                        del row[-1]
                        all.append(row)
                        row.insert(0, count)
                        break
        writer.writerows(all)
```

I want to type "python python.py 2000" and then have my temp.csv look like this:

```
a,b,c,d,e,
0,100,0,0,0
0,1500,0,0,0
```

So the y argument (sys.argv[1]) would be the upper limit for how many rows based on the b values. So if the 4th line is 3700 and i type 4000 it prints out all rows until 3700 is last one (because 5060 is more than 4000).

The problem is now that the kount doesn't work. I can't access the values of b column.

Comment: You are not accessing the data as a list, but as a string (you are comparing 2000 with ',' which python evaluates as less than). You need to do something like `kount = int(row.split(',')[1])` or (probably?) `kount = eval(row)[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the value of column `b` to an integer to ba able to do that comparison, i.e. compare `y` with `int(kount)`. This works (rewriting the code a bit for clarity):

```
import csv, os, sys
y = int(sys.argv[1])

with open("csvinput.csv", 'rb') as input, open('temp.csv', 'wb') as output:
        reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter = ',')
        writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = ',')

        header = next(reader)
        outdata = []
        outdata.append(header)

        for row in reader:
                kount = int(row[1])
                if y > kount:
                        outdata.append(row)

        writer.writerows(outdata)
```

Edit: Your code will also produce a csv where b > y, the opposite of what you are trying to achieve. And it removes columns i a funny way, leaving you with 5 columns in the header, and 4 in the body

Comment: Thank you this is EXACTLY what I wanted. Sorry, i forgot some things in the first code which didnt probably make sense like the dels and counts and the ID.